Exactly Onces in Flink or Kafka Streams
I have a question when you speak of exactly onces semantic in flink or KafkaStreams , can you guarantee exactly onces for example if you topology call a rest api (in some point of you topology) and then fail in some point. if  the application rebuild the state from rocksDB or Checkpoint . the aplication  can  re invoke the REST api for the same row (twice)or I need some mechanism to control that issue?
For explample in flink I know use transactions to manage sink write and have two commit (pre commit and commit). but i dont know if i have that control for the rest api
solved my problem thanks.

if you're calling an external system, there is always the risk that you don't receive the answer, and so you cannot know if you should retry the api call. All that the stream knows is whether your application has received and acknowledged a row.
